# need the name of http_host for a htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to write a rule where I don't know the exact http_host.

For example I have `(www.)?example.com`. 
Now I need `example` to build the following:

`(www.)?example.com/example/...` in a RewriteRule.

So how can I split the http_host into name only?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get just the domain name, less the TLD. Then you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z-]+)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/ [R,L]
```

Where `%1` is just the domain name. eg. `example` in your *example*.

This assumes a TLD of `.com`.